# r solve linear equation

Tags: r, solver

This is my equation

```
k_0 = 0.21
k_1 = 0.21
m = 52

alpha = 0.05
beta  = 0.2
pi_0 = 0.669
pi_1 to be estimated
power <- 1-beta
cz <- 20
z_alpha <- qnorm(p= alpha/2, lower.tail=FALSE)
Z_beta <- qnorm(p= beta, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

If this is my equation, how do I solve for pi or estimate pi given values for all other parameters ?

```
 cz  <- 1 + ((z_alpha + Z_beta)^2)*((pi_0*(1-pi_0)/m+ pi_1*(1- pi_1)/m + (((k_0)^2)*((pi_0)^2) + ((k_1)^2)*((pi_1)^2)))/((pi_0 - pi_1)^2))
```

Comment: Maybe you should write a function?

Comment: What is `m` in your equation?

Comment: Just a side comment: assigning an object to the name of `c` is not a great idea because it can cause confusion with function `c()`.

Comment: @fbeese, thanks for catching that error m=52, I have updated my question with this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(minpack.lm)

k_0 = 0.21
k_1 = 0.21
m = 52

alpha = 0.05
beta  = 0.2
pi_0 = 0.669

power <- 1-beta
cz <- 20
z_alpha <- qnorm(p= alpha/2, lower.tail=FALSE)
Z_beta <- qnorm(p= beta, lower.tail=FALSE)

fun <- as.formula(cz  ~ 1 + ((z_alpha + Z_beta)^2)*((pi_0*(1-pi_0)/m + pi_1*(1 - pi_1)/m + (((k_0)^2)*((pi_0)^2) + ((k_1)^2)*((pi_1)^2)))/((pi_0 - pi_1)^2)))
df <- data.frame(cz, z_alpha, Z_beta, alpha, m, beta, pi_0, k_0, k_1)

#Fitting model using minpack.lm package
nls.out <- nlsLM(fun, 
                  data = df,
                  start=list(pi_1=1),
                  algorithm = "LM",
                  control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500))

summary(nls.out)

#> Formula: cz ~ 1 + ((z_alpha + Z_beta)^2) * ((pi_0 * (1 - pi_0)/m + pi_1 * 
#>    (1 - pi_1)/m + (((k_0)^2) * ((pi_0)^2) + ((k_1)^2) * ((pi_1)^2)))/((pi_0 - 
#>    pi_1)^2))
#>
#> Parameters:
#>      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> pi_1   0.8219        NaN     NaN      NaN
#>
#> Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#>
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

It could have been better if you have used series of values for dependent and independent variables. The constants may have single values. You have to tell which are the constants (i.e. parameters) in your equation.

Comment: Thanks, the estimate '0.8219` matches with the answer I was expecting. However this is more like a solve the linear equation , what is the value of x given all other values  ? type of question and not parameter estimation based on linear model, is it not ? I could be wrong, what do you think ?